# iTEBD\iDMRG for gapless systems

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, tensor-network

I have learned that the Matrix Product State (MPS) formulation can only handle systems where the entropy scales up to logarithmically. For gapped systems, as the entanglement entropy is constant, a constant bond dimension independent of the size is enough, while for gapless systems, as the entanglement entropy scales in the system size, the bond dimension must be increased with increasing the size.

My question is how does this analysis extend to the iTEBD/iDMRG algorithm, where we consider infinite chains? Is there a distinction between gapped/gapless systems anymore?

Comment: Please consider spelling out the acronyms.

Comment: Yes: Also for infinite systems, approximating gapped systems is easier than approximating gapless systems.